# Laravel 4 input option

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got an controller code that says:

```
             $player->town_id = $input['town'];

         // this is located mostly in the config.lua

         $player->posx = '95';  // posx (X)
         $player->posy = '117';   // posy (Y)
         $player->posz = '7';  // posz (Z)
```

also here's the view (part of view that you need):

```
       <div class="control-group">
    {{ Form::label('town', 'Town:') }}
      <div class="controls">
{{ Form::select('town', array('1' => 'Main Town', '2' => 'Second Town'), '1'); }}
 </div>
</div>
```

You see, what I want is to set a config or something like an if statement. If the town is set to Main Town (which is equals to 1) then it will be like this:

```
         $player->posx = '95';  // posx (X)
         $player->posy = '117';   // posy (Y)
         $player->posz = '7';  // posz (Z)
```

else if the user selects Second Town (which is equals to 2), it'll use a different postion:

```
         $player->posx = '1000';  // posx (X)
         $player->posy = '1000';   // posy (Y)
         $player->posz = '7';  // posz (Z)
```

Is there an if statement or something that I could use in this case?

Comment: Where do you want to put that condition (if statement)? In the controller, the view or the select?

Comment: Where do you want to use it (if condition) ?

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo
In the controller.

Comment: Are you submitting the form ?

Comment: Yeah, I have a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can use

```
// Other code, assuming that $player already exists

if(Input::has('town')) {
    if(Input::get('town') == 1) {
        $player->posx = '95';
        $player->posy = '117';
        $player->posz = '7'; 
    }
    elseif(Input::get('town') == 2) {
        $player->posx = '1000';
        $player->posy = '1000';
        $player->posz = '7';
    }
}
```